# Ligas de reputação (link quebrado)

Tags: bug, suporte, status-intencional

O seguinte link, disponível na [página de usuários do SOPT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users), está quebrado:

> [ligas de reputação semanais/mensais/trimestrais](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/week/br-stackoverflow)

Comment: Eu não acho que sites no beta privado possuam ligas de reputação... Quando o site for lançado (ou colocado no beta público) veremos se o link continua quebrado.

Answer (score 2):

As ligas hoje estão disponíveis aqui:

http://stackexchange.com/leagues/273/week/pt-stackoverflow